# Python - pulling data from files and inserting into an array includes '\n'. How to not include it so I can sort on text and change it?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have .txt files that have categorization labels for images with each different label on a separate line. 
 Maximum number of labels, or lines, is 7.  It looks something like this in varying numbers of labels and order:

label1

label3

label2

label5

When I pull the data into an array it is including the '\n' (for new line) and viewing the data in one line.  I am expecting something like this for 3 files:

y=([label1,label3,label2, label5], [label1], [label5,label2,label3])

or at least

y=((label1,label3,label2, label5), (label1), (label5,label2,label3))

My code is as follows:

```
y=[ ]
for path in [f for f in os.listdir(DATA_DIR) if f[-4:] == ".png"]:  # for .png files in directory
    with open(DATA_DIR + path[:-4] + ".txt", "rU") as s:  # opens a .txt file of same name as image
        label = s.read()
        #print(label)
    y.append(label)
```

This, however gives me what is in the file separated by the new line code '\n'.  I thought the "rU" removed the '\n' values in the data and allowed it to be properly put into a list or array.

Comment: look into rstrip() or str.replace("\n", "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want

```
y.append(label.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Yay!  Now on to the next step.  Thank you all so much!!

Comment: print(y[5])  gives ['label5','label1']

print(y[900]) gives ['label1','label3','label4']

Comment: `.splitlines()` is the proper solution, it will properly handle any newline marker.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use str.splitlines() for this, it will handle the various line breaks for you.